# magento page is not redirecting when install on wamp

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise

I have tried a lot of time to install Magento on Wamp and it always gives error "page is not redirecting properly".I searched on google and applied various solutions but not getting its solution.

Comment: Do you have this issue in the frontend, admin or during installation? Are you using Chorome?

Answer (score 2):

Please be sure that mod-rewrite is enabled and that your virtual host config or httpd.conf setting in Apache for AllowOverride is set to All.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: I solved using enable mod-rewrite.